# InnoDB table errors: Doesn't exist/exist. Orphaned tables? Invisible database in mysql command clients

Tags: mysql, excel, innodb, invisible, orphan

I had this problem for a while but somehow worked around it without solving the problem. Whenever I try selecting/creating/droping a table, it gives me a doesn't exist/exists error. All tables are InnoDB. I see the tables via `SHOW TABLES` command. I changed my.cnf by adding a line:

> [mysqld]
>
> innodb_file_per_table

I still get these errors. My database is named `My_Database`. I created a new database called ***`my_database`*** (notice the lower-case letters) with the same tables. ***`my_database`*** works perfectly fine; no table errors. The ***`my_database`*** folder has the .frm and matching .ibd files per table. Now the problem is that `SHOW DATABASES` shows me the `My_Database` but not the ***`my_database`***. Furthermore, `My_Database` still has the table errors. In order to manipulate ***`my_database`*** I have to type in `USE` ***`my_database`***. I have to do the same method in phpmyadmin.

In summary, I have an invisible working database. I cannot access this database with mySQL for Excel. I really need this function for the work environment. All names have no weird characters.

Answer (score 1):

Ok nevermind. I finally fixed it. After adding the lines

> [mysqld]
>
> innodb_file_per_table

to my.cnf, I dropped the whole database. Of course I dumped it earlier and recreated + restored the database. No problems here.